# How to delist subset strings if it is a substring of another string

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a list of strings in my database let say in a column

```
understand
understan
understa
underst
unders
under
```

I'm trying to find out How to delist subset strings if it is a substring of another string with sql?

So I if we pretend that this is a column of my table, the end result must be only

```
understand
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete all records except shown then try something similar to

```sql
DELETE dataset.table t1
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1
               FROM dataset.table t2
               WHERE t2.word LIKE CONCAT(t1.word, '_%') )
```

If you want to select only shown record use

```sql
SELECT *
FROM dataset.table t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                   FROM dataset.table t2
                   WHERE t2.word LIKE CONCAT(t1.word, '_%') )
```

Comment: DELETE ????????

Comment: @SNaRe You want that the table contains one record only in the result state - i.e. all another are to be deleted. Or you want something else?

Comment: I don't want them to be deleted but I want them to be filtered.